# Showing a file choosing dialog for a tree view column that contains paths

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I'm trying to show a [`GtkFileChooserDialog`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html) when a [`GtkTreeView`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkTreeView.html) [column](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkTreeViewColumn.html) that contains paths is edited.

I've come up with 2 possible ways to implement this:

1. Hook the [`"editing-started"`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkCellRenderer.html#GtkCellRenderer-editing-started) signal on the [`GtkCellRendererText`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkCellRendererText.html) that shows the path. However this still requires that the "editing" be done inside the cell. I can't show a dialog and then [cancel](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkCellRenderer.html#gtk-cell-renderer-stop-editing) the usual editing process.
2. Add a "..." button [into the column](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkTreeViewColumn.html#gtk-tree-view-column-pack-end). Catch [`"clicked"`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked) signals on the button, and use this to show the dialog. However only [`GtkCellRenderer`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkCellRenderer.html)s can be added to a column, so I have no idea how to implement this.

How should I proceed? What's the standard method to edit paths in a `GtkTreeView`?

Answer (score 1):

You can override CellRendererText's `do_start_editing` method to completely change its behaviour:

```
class CellRendererFile(gtk.CellRendererText):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.CellRendererText.__init__(self)
        self.props.editable = True

    def do_start_editing(self, event, widget, path, background_area, cell_area, flags):
        # TODO: Show dialog.
        self.emit('edited', path, "TODO: Dialog output")

gobject.type_register(CellRendererFile)
```

And then just use normally, connect to the "edited" signal.

Comment: I tried this by calling self.editing_stopped in the "editing-started" handler, and that didn't work. I'll try it this way thanks.